# How do I make for my program to run again after it asked the user to press 1 to continue?

Tags: java

I have a program where a user has to select an element of their choice from the linear search array. My program should display the question and the given array again when an user enters 1 to continue. I'm not sure where the while loop have to be and what code should be in the while loop, because if the user enters 1 to continue my program does not continue it just ends 
Here my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchArray 
{

public  static int Search(int[] data, int key)
{

 for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
   {
        if (data[i] == key)
            {
                return i;
            }//end of if statement
   }//end of for loop
        return -1;
 }//end of search method 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] data= {74,56,45,14,78,100};
    for(int element: data)
    {
        System.out.print(element + " , "); 
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the key of your choice: ");
    int key = in.nextInt();
    int index = Search(data, key);
    int option = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue: ");
    while(option ==1)
    {

        option=in.nextInt();
    }
    if(index!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Found at index: " + Search(data, key));
        }//end of if statement
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Is not found ");
        }//end of else statement

}//end of main method 
}//end of main class
```

Comment: To repeat things in a loop, the code that you want to repeat needs to be _inside the loop_. If you want the whole (or majority) of what's in your `main` method to repeat, then you need a loop around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new class of itself. ie

```
if(sc.nextInt() == 1){
   SearchArray sa = new SearchArray();
   sa.main();
}
```

Comment: I never thought of doing it this way, this is perfect

Comment: @nadinejansen as  the main is a static method you can even try `SearchArray.main(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this main method

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] data = {74, 56, 45, 14, 78, 100};
    for (int element : data) {
        System.out.print(element + " , ");
    }


    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the key of your choice: ");
        int key = in.nextInt();
        int index = Search(data, key);
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Found at index: " + index);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue: ");
        while (in.nextInt() != 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue: ");
        }
    }
}
```